# PLSQL Program to truncate and store the country code in the list of phone numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql

for ex : I have a field called ph_no = 0091826454646 and call_dest=IV , so i need to truncate the country code from number as 91 if call_dest+IV and store it in a field like 'country_code'. 
the ph_no can also be like 91826454646. so it can start from 00 or directly the country code. 
Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
   SET country_code =
          CASE
             WHEN ph_no LIKE '00%'
                THEN SUBSTR (ph_no, 3, 2)
             ELSE SUBSTR (ph_no, 1, 2)
          END
 WHERE call_dest = 'IV';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select case call_dest when 'IV' then if(length(ph_no)=11,substr(ph_no,1,2),substr(ph_no,3,2))
end as country_code from table_ph;
```

Hope it helps!!